# Creating a set of views takes a long time (Appcelerator) and blocks user interactions on iOS only

Tags: javascript, appcelerator, appcelerator-alloy

I am creating a list (ScrollView) with some custom "rows" ([The image contains a single "row"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EItKj.png)). I show 5 rows and have added an event listener so that when the user scrolls to the end, 5 more elements are loaded and displayed. I made this using Alloy but I noticed it was taking too long so I tried writing the views manually.

```js
// created the views programmatically to see if there was any difference from Alloy

function createRow(args) {
 var container = Ti.UI.createView({
  layout: "vertical",
  width: Ti.UI.FILL,
  height: "42dp"
 });
 var rowContent = Ti.UI.createView({
  width: Titanium.UI.FILL,
  height: "41dp", //Titanium.UI.FILL,
  layout: "horizontal",
  left: "16dp",
  right: "16dp"
 });
 var border = Ti.UI.createView({
  left: "16dp",
  right: "16dp",
  height: "1dp",
  backgroundColor: Colors.darkGrey
 });
 
 var titleScroll = Ti.UI.createScrollView({
  scrollType: "horizontal",
  width: "49%",
  horizontalWrap: false
 });
 var scrollContainer = Ti.UI.createScrollView({
  scrollType: "horizontal",
  horizontalWrap: false,
  width: "50%"
 });
 var scroll = Ti.UI.createView({
  layout: "horizontal",
  horizontalWrap: false,
  right: 0,
  width: Ti.UI.SIZE,
  height: Titanium.UI.SIZE
 });
 var title = Ti.UI.createLabel({
  text: args.title,
  font: args.isTitle ? {font: "Lato-Regular", fontSize: "22dp"} : {fontFamily: "Lato-Regular", fontSize: "15"},
  horizontalWrap: false,
  wordWrap: false,
  left: 0,
  color: Colors.grey,
  minimumFontSize: "15dp"
 });
 if(args.value) {
  var t = args.value.join();
   
  scroll.add(Ti.UI.createLabel({
   text: t,
   color: args.action ? Colors.blue : Colors.black,
   font: {fontSize: "15dp", fontFamily: "Lato-Regular"},
   right: "5dp",
   width: Ti.UI.SIZE,
   horizontalWrap: false,
   wordWrap: false,
   minimumFontSize: "15dp"
  }));
 }
 
 if(args.data)
  scrollContainer.data = args.data; //just a dump of the data used by the click handler
  
 if(args.action)
  scrollContainer.addEventListener("click",args.action);
 
 scrollContainer.add(scroll);
 titleScroll.add(title);
 rowContent.add(titleScroll);
 rowContent.add(scrollContainer);
 container.add(rowContent);
 container.add(border);
 
 return container; //Ti.UI.View
}

function createHeader(args) {
 var header = Ti.UI.createView({
  layout: "horizontal",
  height: "44dp",
  backgroundColor: "#fff"
 });
 
 var leftView = Ti.UI.createView({
  width: "25%",
  height: Ti.UI.FILL
 });
 var rightView = Ti.UI.createView({
  width: "25%",
  height: Ti.UI.FILL
 });
 var centerView = Ti.UI.createView({
  width: "49%",
  height: Ti.UI.FILL
 });
 var verticalAligner = Ti.UI.createView({
  height: Ti.UI.SIZE,
  width: Ti.UI.SIZE,
  layout: "vertical"
 });
 var headerTitle = Ti.UI.createLabel({
  color: Colors.green,
  font: {fontSize: "16.5dp", fontFamily: "Lato-Regular"},
  textAlign: "center",
  horizontalWrap: false,
  wordWrap: false
 });
 var headerSubtitle = Ti.UI.createLabel({
  font: {fontSize: "14dp", fontFamily: "Lato-Regular"},
  textAlign: "center",
  color: Colors.grey,
  horizontalWrap: false,
  wordWrap: false
 });
 
 if(args.rightView)
  rightView.add(args.rightView);
 if(args.leftView)
  leftView.add(args.leftView);
 
 verticalAligner.add(headerTitle);
 verticalAligner.add(headerSubtitle);
 centerView.add(verticalAligner);
 header.add(leftView);
 header.add(centerView);
 header.add(rightView);
 
 headerTitle.text = args.title;
 headerSubtitle.text = args.subTitle;
  
 return header;
}

function createBlock(args) {
 var container = Ti.UI.createView({
  layout: "vertical",
  width: "100%",
  height: Ti.UI.SIZE
 });
 var covers = Ti.UI.createView({ //
  height: "119dp"
 });
 var content = Ti.UI.createView({
  height: Ti.UI.SIZE,
  layout: "vertical"
 });
 function goToEvent() {
  Storage.event.id = args.event;
  Alloy.Globals.openWin("event");
 }
 
 var data = new D.data();
 var w = Android ? Ti.Platform.displayCaps.platformWidth :  Measure.dpToPX(Ti.Platform.displayCaps.platformWidth);
 var h = Measure.dpToPX(119); //Android ? Alloy.Globals.dpToPX(119) : Measure.dpToPX(119);
 if(args.images) {
  //setTimeout(function() { //timeout didn't make any difference
   var image = null;
   //for(var i = 0; i < args.images.length; i++) {
    image = Ti.UI.createImageView({
     image: data.getBlobResized({ //returns a URL for the picture 
      id: args.images[0], //i
      width: w,
      height: h
     }),
     width: iOS ? Measure.pxToDP(w) : Alloy.Globals.pxToDP(w),
     height: iOS ? Measure.pxToDP(h): Alloy.Globals.pxToDP(h)
    });
    image.addEventListener("click",goToEvent);
    covers.add(image); //addView
   //}
  //},0);
 }
 
 var row = null;
 
 if(args.rows) {
  for(var j=0; j < args.rows.length; j++) {
   //row = Alloy.createController("index/events/block/row",args.rows[j]).getView();
   content.add(createRow(args.rows[j]));
  }
 }
 
 container.add(createHeader(args));
 container.add(covers);
 container.add(content);
 
 return container;
}
```

In particular, in the code provided, I call 4 times the function `createRow()` which creates a row inside the element ([as seen in the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cpOQN.png)). **This function takes 7ms to 10ms** to run for some reason. So calling it 4 times means it slows the whole process **28-40ms**.

On *Android* the app doesn't lag at all. On *iOS* it stops user interaction completely until these operations are done

- Using latest Titanium SDK (5.2.2GA) on Appcelerator Studio
- Testing on iPhone 5, iOS simulator (4s,5,6,6s)

Thank you for your help

Comment: Hello ani, why you dont use a listview or a tableview?

Comment: I tried using a tableView and the result is slow. It's not the scrollView that is causing the problem. It's the creation of the element I add in the scrollView.

Comment: I think you're using bad practices for appcelerator, sorry.
Appcelerator works very well with good practice, development is not easy. I recommend you read a little more official documentation

Comment: Can you give me any hint on what I'm doing wrong? I've been using Appcelerator for more than 5 years

Comment: e.g: you use many views.
tip: Avoid a deep hierarchy of views

Comment: Thanks. I don't think it's gonna be easy to get the result I want in less views

Comment: Try to use a listview, in this days I rewrited a lot of scrollview/tableview for my company, and the difference is incredible, there were lists that take 3-4 seconds to load, now they load almost instantly and the code is also incredibly more beautiful IMHO. Listviews seems some strange voodoo magic if you open the documentation coming from a tableview but if you understand them they are really easy.

Comment: @AlbertoPastrolin Thanks I'll try that, but as I pointed out in my previous comments, the problem is not in the scrollview but when I call the functions above which take 60ms to complete which might not seem a lot but consider it times 5 or 10 (items are laid out at multiples of 5) and it gets to 300ms of a blocked UI that the user can't use. I will try using a list view, not that I haven't already.

Comment: @AniSinanaj Yes, I understood your problem, from my little experience with appcelerator I noticed that sometimes alloy performs better, sometimes titanium, for example I had a calendar done with a scrollable view in alloy (xml) and the pages as tableview (switched to scrollview hoping for better performance) added at runtime, simply also creating the scrollableview at runtime suddendly the creation times became 10 times smaller, switching to listviews improved this creation times again; it is tedious but if the creation time is crucial, try to bench parts of the function and look what is slow.

Comment: @AlbertoPastrolin That's exactly what I've done, I tried it initially with Alloy, then switched to runtime creation of the tables and now tried it with ListVews. I tried to see what portion of the code makes it lag with no success. I've done similar apps and they're all quite fast and don't lag at all. Using ListView it still Lags but I'm still testing the scrolling to see if it is improved at all. Thanks though :)